Are VStar and VMax pokemon V pokemon?
For Mimikyu's Ability Safeguard, is it protected form VStars and VMaxs?
Mimikyu Ability

Safeguard: Prevent all damage done to this Pokémon by attacks from your opponent's Pokémon ex and Pokémon V


Does this answer your question? In Pokemon, what is a V card?

Yes, VStar and VMax Pokémon are Pokémon V as well, according to the rulebook, page 28:

And although Pokémon VMAX are a different stage, they are still considered Pokémon V—so if something affects Pokémon V, it also affects Pokémon VMAX.

The same comments appear in the sections for V-Union and VStar Pokémon.
Thus, Safeguard would prevent damage from Pokemon VMAX or Pokémon VStar.
